# What subjective questions are there on the main site?

Tags: discussion, subjective

The impending closure of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21101/game-review-websites-without-review-scores for being one of

1. a shopping recommendation,
2. unrelated to gaming because it's really about websites, or
3. a "bad" subjective question

has me curious, are there any examples of [good subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) on GSE?

Most of the past meta-posts about [subjective](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective) questions seem to contain questions that are all either closed or deleted because they likely are too *argumentative*,  but I can't seem to find any that are still around.

In any case, the question that brought me here doesn't seem like it fits well into the "good subjective" mould, but would anything on GSE?

Comment: The only other close reason than the one you yourself provide is "It's an itemized list", which is something we can work around as has been done many times in the past. Itemized lists have problems of their own that are unrelated to the 3 impending options you've provided.

Answer (score 3):

[Does playing racing games with a wheel and pedals affect your real-world driving?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8639/does-playing-racing-games-with-a-wheel-and-pedals-affect-your-afk-driving)

...and...

[Is Super Meat Boy really harder with a keyboard?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20886/is-super-meat-boy-really-harder-with-a-keyboard)

are the first two examples I can think of, mostly just because I know they were around.

Also, some questions we get about strategies to defeat opponents in PvP tend to be subjective in nature.

Comment: I would go so far as to say all PvP strategy questions and answers are subjective. Heck, half the StarCraft 2 questions have good, subjective answers.

Comment: @Jason I'm mostly agreed. Admittedly, the first revision of this question went as: `all → many → most → some`. Mostly because I was unsure if there might have actually been some non-subjective questions and I felt it still kept the illustration of the point (that a lot of our content is in fact subjective) without forcing the matter.